# customizing mkisofs as cross-platform as possible

Tags: bash, dvd, iso-image

I have a relatively large archive from which my students would select files to create iso images, which they take home on their pen drives to burn their own DVDs.

In order to make the process as hassle free as possible I need to know:

1) the options to make the iso images as cross-platform as possible

2) given a variable list of files, using a bash script I already grouped and split them in order in smaller file lists, so that they would fit in the types of disks they would burn their images to, but I need to know how to instruct mkisofs to replicate the file structure starting from a certain depth. I don't want for those images to contain the whole paths of every single file

Say those would be the paths to the files:

/media/sdbX/public/HS47/edu/mit/techtv/collections/physicsdemos/14298-charge-and-electric-field-of-a-hollow-conductor.mp4

/media/sdbX/public/HS47/com/youtube/EducationCommonsRW/S0wbEl7caTY.mp4

/media/sdbX/public/HS47/edu/mit/techtv/collections/physicsdemos/14366-field-of-a-sphere-and-an-infinite-plane.mp4

I would like for the paths in my students' images to look like:

mit/techtv/collections/physicsdemos/14298-charge-and-electric-field-of-a-hollow-conductor.mp4

youtube/EducationCommonsRW/S0wbEl7caTY.mp4

mit/techtv/collections/physicsdemos/14366-field-of-a-sphere-and-an-infinite-plane.mp4

How do you do that?

thanks
 lbrtchx

Comment: Are these data disks for use in a computer and double-clicking on the files? Or are these supposed to be burned as DVD MPEG2 for playback in a DVD player? Are you creating the ISO images, or are they?

Comment: Of course I want for them to be able to play the files back using their a DVD player from whichever operating system (they mostly use Windows and Mac, but some use Linux as I do myself).

 Kids constantly come in with whatever "greatest and latest" stuff they have

 lbrtchx

Answer (score 0):

`mkisofs` should already place the files in the correct location:

```
mkisofs -o HS47.iso /media/sdbX/public/HS47/
```

Should result in the files on the disk where you want them (i.e., place the entire contents of `/media/sdbX/public/HS47/` at the root of the disk image).

As to being the most compatible, I would try with the default options, and ask here about more specific problems if you encounter them.

Keep in mind that these disks will require being opened in a computer, and will not work in a basic DVD player (the kind that you would connect directly to a TV).

---

After rereading your question, I think this might be what you're looking for:

Try using `-graft-points`. This allows you to place specific files at specific locations on the disk. Your above example would look like this (Note `\` is used as line-continuation for readability):

```
mkisofs -o Disk1.iso -graft-points \
mit/techtv/collections/physicsdemos/=/media/sdbX/public/HS47/edu/mit/techtv/collections/physicsdemos/14298-charge-and-electric-field-of-a-hollow-conductor.mp4 \
youtube/EducationCommonsRW/=/media/sdbX/public/HS47/com/youtube/EducationCommonsRW/S0wbEl7caTY.mp4 \
mit/techtv/collections/physicsdemos/=/media/sdbX/public/HS47/edu/mit/techtv/collections/physicsdemos/14366-field-of-a-sphere-and-an-infinite-plane.mp4
```

`-graft-points` tells `mkisofs` that the paths are in the  `folder/=filePath` format, where `folder` is the folder on the disk where the file should show up, and `filePath` is the location on your computer where it should get the file from to place in the image. You can include as many files as you want this way, and `mkisofs` will merge them together into a single image, creating nested folders as necessary.

Comment: using the command line you wrote all files

Comment: by using the command line you suggested: "mkisofs -o HS47.iso /media/sdbX/public/HS47/" you are assuming that all directory branches go from that path, which is not the case. I didn't explain myself well enouth and/or you didn't read my question.
 I don't know how to make my question clearer or how could my problem be more specific. Obviously I would not be asking that question here if I could use the standard options.